# Method call in angular subscription out of scope of component property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a method that is called in various places of my component like so:

```
this.updateResults();
```

This method relies on a couple of properties on the component.  The method works fine in my methods called from the template but I want it to work after the queryParams are changed so I use this code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.navigationSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.updateResults();
      }
    });
  }
```

The method executes at expected time but I can see in the debugger that the required properties are null when it executes.

In the debugger the component appears as `_this` instead of `this`.  So this is why `this.propertyName` isn't working I think.

It seems when it is being called the component is out of scope.  How do I bind this method call to the scope of the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const _this = this;
    this.navigationSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            _this.updateResults();
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure if the scope is really an issue in your case, but this approach saved me sometimes already.